# Playing Multiple Sounds at Once Using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have a set of UIButtons. Every time I press a button, a sound plays. The issue: When you press one button and the sound behind to play, when you press the second button the sound coming from the first button stops.

This question has been asked a million times. The solution is always to create a new instance of AVAudioPlayer each time. I've tried that, to no avail. I've read the docs, read through every question on StackOverflow related to this, and have had no luck. When I use SystemSoundID they play simultaneously each time... But I have to sacrifice volume control ability. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
 NSString *soundOne = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:senderString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[soundOne stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

    switch ([sender tag]) {

        case 1:
            [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
            [_audioPlayer play];
            NSLog(@"Playing: %@", soundOne);
            break;

        case 2:
            [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
            [_audioPlayer play];
            NSLog(@"Playing: %@", soundOne);
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your code, while making a new audio player, also destroys the old audio player. You have to have two audio players *existing at the same time* in order to get them to play two sounds at the same time. That can't possibly happen when you have only one instance variable `_audioPlayer`.

Comment: So I need to add `_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];` into each case?

Comment: Try _audioPlayer1 and _audioPlayer2 instead

Comment: I think what's needed here is a basic understanding of what a variable is. You can't put two shoes into one shoebox...

Comment: @matt I understand variables just fine, AVAudioPlayer is what I do not understand.

Comment: @John I don't think you do. If you did, you wouldn't be asking the question you are asking. Try to remember that you are the questioner - that means you _don't_ understand. A major feature of variables is that they cause the thing they refer to persist. If you have `_audioPlayer` referring to an AVAudioPlayer, and you set `_audioPlayer` to another AVAudioPlayer - which is what you have been doing - then the first AVAudioPlayer is no longer referred to, and thus ceases to exist. That is why the sound stops: there is nothing to make that sound any more.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt)'s answer, playing the second sound destroys the first.

Consider this:

```
x = 3
```

We just set `x` to equal `3`. Now, we need to store another number, `4`. Now, we have this:

```
x = 4
```

Wait, we just assigned `x` to be `4`. We forgot `3`. We need a second variable to hold `3`. Why not `y`?

```
y = 3
```

There we go. Now we have `x = 4` and `y = 3`. Two variables, holding two values.

This goes along with instances of audio players. Whether the button is the first or second, **the audio player is being reset to be an instance of whatever sound you want to play.** So, what happens is, the audio player forgets the first sound and plays the second. It's like resetting `x` to be `4`, not `3`.

Just like the solution above, **you need a second variable.**

---

Replace this in your `.h` file...

```
@property AVAudioSession* audioPlayer;
```

with...

```
@property AVAudioSession* audioPlayer1;
@property AVAudioSession* audioPlayer2;
```

---

May I notice also, in your code, you always re-initialize the audio player every time a sound plays, and you only have one sound set to play. In your `.m` file, copy/paste this function, or add the relevant code into your `init` function.

```
-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self->_audioPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:Sound1] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]];
        self->_audioPlayer2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:Sound2] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]];
        [self->_audioPlayer1 prepareToPlay];
        [self->_audioPlayer2 prepareToPlay];
    }
}
```

And, in your `.h` file, add:

```
#define Sound1 @"your first key name"
#define Sound2 @"your second key name"
```

Finally, you can switch the code in your function to just this:

```
NSLog(@"Playing sound with sender tag: %i", [sender tag]);
switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 1:
    {
        [_audioPlayer1 play];
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        [_audioPlayer2 play];
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        break;
    }
}
```